# Forward declaration and friend function

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend

Following the question here
if I omit the namespace like this:

```
void f(window);

  class window{
    private:
    int a;
    friend void ::f(window);
  };

void f(window rhs){
  std::cout << rhs.a << std::endl;
}
```

I get strange behavior:

```
friend void f(window);
```

Compiles without forward declaration of f(window), but

```
friend void ::f(window);
```

Does not:

```
error C2039: 'f' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

Can someone explain the reason for it? Why does :: makes this difference, if we are in the global namespace anyway...

Thank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't qualify `f` in the friend declaration, it also behaves like a normal declaration and declares `f` in the surrounding namespace (global in your case).

However, if you explicitly qualify it as `::f`, it is no longer a declaration of `f`, but only a friend declaration which wants to reference an already declared `f`. But there is none, hence the error.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that.  Unqualified, the friend declaration declares the function in the nearest surrounding namespace, but it only introduces the name into the class (but of course, it will be found using ADN).

Comment: I would have accepted @Angew's answer, but I just tested this code with gcc and there both cases compile without forward declaration... Can anyone explain why?